# Foreign key is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

**tb_tests**:

```
`id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
(...)`
```

and

**tb_files**:
`id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
test_id INT(6) UNSIGNED,
FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES tb_tests(id),
(...)`

I am facing problem because foreign key `test_id` is empty. I want reference between these two tables so I could easily identify in future which *file* (or multiple files) is linked to which *test*.
May be I have bad thinking and is another solution.

Two tables are InnoDB.

Comment: can you create mysql fiddle and share with dummy data ,then I can try some for you!

Comment: thanks in advance ;)  Here is [tb_tests](http://pasteboard.co/8tNYPLA94.jpg) and [tb_files](http://pasteboard.co/8tOhVoaAi.jpg).  Sorry, sqlfiddle seems doesn't work for me. As you can see in `test_id` I have `NULL`, but should be 1, 1, 2, 2

Answer (score 0):

Its seems on create or update the fileld `test_id` is not getting feeded change the attribute of the filed `test_id` to not null.

```
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
test_id INT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (test_id) REFERENCES tb_tests(id),
(...)
```

You get error on create or update if you are not passing `test_id`